# Changing IP address/restarting netplan

Tags: ansible

I have a very simple ansible playbook that replaces the /etc/netplan/config.yml.

and then restarts netplan.

The issue is that when restarting netplan the IP address changes, so ansible hangs indeffinatly.

How can i avoid this? I want to just run the command and not wait for a response, or run a command and then test on the new IP.

I can't find anything in the documentation,

Its a very simple role -

```
task/main.yml
- name: Updating Network Configuration
  template: src=config.yml dest=/etc/netplan/config.yaml
  notify: start netplan


handlers/main.yml
- name: start netplan
  shell: netplan apply
```

I'd like to add, just tried this..which should fire/forget but it still hangs

```
- name: start netplan
  shell: netplan apply
  async: 1
  poll: 0
```

Comment: WC to SO. Please update the question with all the details needed such as Playbook. Updating the playbook in the questions will help us to understand

Comment: You tried async and "it still hangs". It should not. Try and increase the timeout "async: 45".

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same issue and `async` worked fine for me :

```
- name: Apply netplan
  command: sudo netplan apply
  async: 45
  poll: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround for this problem. Use two IP addresses. This will keep the SSH session open the whole time.

You can create multiple .yaml files in /etc/netplan with different names. When performing a "sudo netplan apply" the netplan will apply the IP addresses in all the .yaml files. You can then configure a new tasks section in your Ansible playbook to access the IP address you want to keep. Use a command: to remove the .yaml you do not want (with the old IP address), and perform a "sudo netplan apply" again. Forgive my messy code below, I just started learning Ansible so not sure if there is a better way to accomplish this.

Note: The script below already had a secondary .yaml file in /etc/netplan, I am just editing the file for my own purposes

```
---
- name: Change the IP Address of the specified server
  hosts: template_vm
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes

  tasks:
          - name: Including Environment Items
            include_vars:
              file: vm_settings.yaml
              name: vm_settings

          - name: uncomment out address lines
            replace:
              path: /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
              regexp: '^#\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s'
              replace: '            '

          - name: set ip address
            replace:
              path: /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
              regexp: 'x.x.x.x'
              replace: '{{vm_settings.ipaddress}}'

          - name: configure DNS 
            lineinfile:
              path: /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
              line: '                - 192.168.1.10'
              insertbefore: .*8.8.8.8

          - name: Apply netplan
            command: sudo netplan apply
            ignore_errors: true

          - name: ping
            shell: ping -c 1 -w 2 '{{vm_settings.ipaddress}}'
            ignore_errors: true

- name: Access new ip address
  hosts: new_vm_ip
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes 

  tasks:
          - name: Including Environment Items
            include_vars:
              file: vm_settings.yaml
              name: vm_settings

          - name: Remove old yaml file created by vmware
            command: rm -f /etc/netplan/99-netcfg-vmware.yaml

          - name: Apply netplan again
            command: sudo netplan apply
            ignore_errors: true

          - name: ping
            shell: ping -c 1 -w 2 '{{vm_settings.ipaddress}}'
            ignore_errors: true
```